# Solution of Implicit function with Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I try to solve the following equation (or at least to find its approximation)

```
Reduce[n/(k*Log2[n - k]) == 6 && k > 0 && n > 0, {k, n}]
```

But it cannot be solved. Is there a method to solve it as n=f(k) (or k=f(n)) or approximate it?

Comment: Assuming that solutions exists in `Reals`, there should an additional condition: $n>k+1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a substitution to simplify it, solve, substitute back and solve again:

```
Reduce[(n Log[2])/(k Log[-k + n]) == 6 && k > 0 && n > 0 /. n -> k u, k]
(*  u > 1 && k == 2^(u/6)/(-1 + u)  *)

% /. u -> n/k // Reduce
(*
k >= (E Log[2])/(3 2^(5/6)) &&
  (n == -((-k Log[2] + 6 k ProductLog[-1, -(Log[2]/(3 2^(5/6) k))])/Log[2]) || 
   n == -((-k Log[2] + 6 k ProductLog[-(Log[2]/(3 2^(5/6) k))]) / Log[2]))
*)
```

Plots:

```
p = Plot[{
    -((-k Log[2] + 6 k ProductLog[-1, -(Log[2]/(3 2^(5/6) k))])/Log[2]),
    -((-k Log[2] + 6 k ProductLog[-(Log[2]/(3 2^(5/6) k))])/Log[2])},
   {k, (E Log[2])/(3 2^(5/6)), 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}];

cp = ContourPlot[(n Log[2])/(k Log[-k + n]) == 6, {k, 0.3, 4}, {n, 0, 
    20}, PlotPoints -> {15, 50}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
   ContourStyle -> {Cyan, AbsoluteThickness[4]}];

Show[cp, p]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

By `Solve`:

```
Solve[n/(k*Log2[n - k]) == 6, n]
(* {{n -> (k (Log[2] - 6 ProductLog[-(Log[2]/(3 2^(5/6) k))]))/Log[2]}} *)
```

If you assume `k=3` then:

```
Reduce[n/(k*Log2[n - k]) == 6 && k > 0 && n > 0 && k == 3, n]
(*k == 3 && (n == (3 (Log[2] - 6 ProductLog[-(Log[2]/(9 2^(5/6)))]))/
Log[2] || 
n == (3 (Log[2] - 6 ProductLog[-1, -(Log[2]/(9 2^(5/6)))]))/Log[2]) *)
```

---

Another method:

In range `0 < k < 10` and `0 < n < 10`:

```
m=50;(* Find 50 solution if exist ? *)
FindInstance[n/(k*Log2[n - k]) == 6 && k > 0 && n > 0 && 0 < k < 10 && 0 < n < 10, {k, n},Reals,m] // N// MatrixForm
(* {{k -> 0.449766, n -> 7.72727}, {k -> 0.444691, 
n -> 7.54545}, {k -> 0.480344, n -> 8.81818}, {k -> 0.485448, 
n -> 9.}, {k -> 0.406717, n -> 2.36364}, {k -> 0.375183, 
n -> 4.90909}, {k -> 0.352836, n -> 3.27273}, {k -> 0.360354, 
n -> 4.18182}, {k -> 0.395312, n -> 5.72727}, {k -> 0.470138, 
n -> 8.45455}, {k -> 0.442159, n -> 7.45455}, {k -> 0.419571, 
n -> 6.63636}, {k -> 0.400052, n -> 5.90909}, {k -> 0.390649, 
n -> 5.54545}, {k -> 0.353387, n -> 3.63636}, {k -> 0.417094, 
n -> 6.54545}, {k -> 0.357474, n -> 4.}, {k -> 0.422056, 
n -> 6.72727}, {k -> 0.498199, n -> 9.45455}, {k -> 0.412167, 
n -> 6.36364}, {k -> 0.459941, n -> 8.09091}, {k -> 0.424549, 
n -> 6.81818}, {k -> 0.49565, n -> 9.36364}, {k -> 0.352516, 
n -> 3.36364}, {k -> 0.439629, n -> 7.36364}, {k -> 0.503294, 
n -> 9.63636}, {k -> 0.4644, n -> 8.25}, {k -> 0.420399, 
n -> 6.66667}, {k -> 0.476091, n -> 8.66667}, {k -> 0.427257, 
n -> 6.91667}, {k -> 0.352582, n -> 3.33333}, {k -> 0.469075, 
n -> 8.41667}, {k -> 0.356316, n -> 3.91667}, {k -> 0.375357, 
n -> 4.91667}, {k -> 0.379255, n -> 5.08333}, {k -> 0.492463, 
n -> 9.25}, {k -> 0.3874, n -> 5.41667}, {k -> 0.411349, 
n -> 6.33333}, {k -> 0.45273, n -> 7.83333}, {k -> 0.391613, 
n -> 5.58333}, {k -> 0.35362, n -> 3.66667}, {k -> 0.373461, 
n -> 4.83333}, {k -> 0.462064, n -> 8.16667}, {k -> 0.471414, 
n -> 8.5}, {k -> 0.434163, n -> 7.16667}, {k -> 0.429555, 
n -> 7.}, {k -> 0.385326, n -> 5.33333}, {k -> 0.457394, 
n -> 8.}, {k -> 0.363065, n -> 4.33333}, {k -> 0.497137, 
n -> 9.41667}}*)

m=100;(*Find 100 solution if exist ? *)
FindInstance[n/(k*Log2[n - k]) == 6 && k > 0 && n > 0 && 0 < k < 10 && 0 < n < 10, {k, n},Reals,m] // N // MatrixForm


ContourPlot[n/(k*Log2[n - k]) == 6, {k, 0, 10}, {n, 0, 10}, 
PlotPoints -> 30, FrameLabel -> Automatic]

ContourPlot[n/(k*Log2[n - k]) == 6, {n, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}, 
PlotPoints -> 30, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]